# Order by desc except

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the query with result:

```
SELECT id, name FROM medic WHERE x=z ORDER BY name ASC

1. Aric
2. Bodi
3. Copi
4. Dori
5. Edo
6. Other
7. Poyo
8. Quex
9. Razix
10. Zika
```

What best if I need to display "**Other**" at the last as result below:

```
1. Aric
2. Bodi
3. Copi
4. Dori
5. Edo
7. Poyo
8. Quex
9. Razix
10. Zika
6. Other
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you can just use the boolean expression:

```
ORDER BY (name <> 'Other') DESC,
         name
```

MySQL treats boolean expressions as numbers in a numeric context, with "1" for true and "0" for false.  (I happen to like this convention and wish other databases had similar support.)  This can be convenient in these cases.

Comment: But this probably wouldn't port to any other database (save MariaDB).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . And I usually prefer standard constructs (which is why your answer deserves an upvote).  This happens to be one case where I prefer the short-hand, probably because C was one of the first languages I learned.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to order using a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name
FROM medic
WHERE x=z
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN name <> 'Other' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    name
```

Comment: Wouldn't that put 'Other' on the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Either use two expressions in the ORDER BY clause, or, we can replace the value we want last with a "high" value.

```
ORDER BY IF(t.name='Other', 'ZZZZZZZ', t.name)
```